# semantic ui react dropdown - updating the options and making the dropdown unselected

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui-react

It seems very simple, but if the dropdown has an item selected and then I change the available options and that new set of options also happens to contain the previously selected item then that item will be automatically selected when options change.

What I want is for the dropdown to be showing its placeholder value whenever options change.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedReport(undefined);
  }, [availableReports]);

<Dropdown
   placeholder="Select Report"
   fluid
   selection
   onChange={(e, data) => handleSelectedReportChange(data)}
   options={availableReports}
   value={selectedReport.value }
></Dropdown>
```

Is it a case of maybe needing to somehow force the component to completely re-render, so it forgets about the previous options?

Comment: I have experienced a similar issue with semantic ui react dropdown. There is an onClick function you can define in Dropdown props. You can check if the previously selected item  is included in the set of options and if that is the case you can dynamically set the placeholder using the state. Seems like a lot of work to do, but can't think any way around of this buggy behavior

Comment: @SinanYaman thanks, but I don't want/need to set the placeholder value in state, because I'm happy with it being the static text that it is.
What I do need is for the dropdown to recognise that no report is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very silly mistake on my part, I needed to make sure that the value property of the dropdown option is unique across the different set of options.